# C++ MPI_Reduce rows of the matrix

Tags: c++, c, matrix, mpi, reduction

I am a new to MPI and struggling to do the global reduce operation for my matrix. I have done the reduction, using the materials I have found. But I want to do this not with a generated 1D arrays, but with the randomly filled 2D matrix rows.

I could not find any materials for reduction and matrix.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rank, size;
    double sum = 0;


    if (MPI_Init(&argc, &argv) != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        perror("Error initializing MPI");
        exit(1);
    }

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int sendbuf[size] = { 0 };
    int recvbuf[size] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sendbuf[i] = 1 + rank + size * i;

    printf("Initial %d: ", rank);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("%d ", sendbuf[i]);
    printf("\n");

        MPI_Reduce(&sendbuf, &recvbuf, size, MPI_INT,
            MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// if I have a matrix A[4][4], I want smth like:
// for(int i = 0; i < rows_number; i++)
//   MPI_Reduce(&A[i], &recvbuf, size, MPI_INT,
//           MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << "Reduced = " << recvbuf[i] << endl;

    }



    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: what are you exactly trying to achieve? the input and output buffers passed to `MPI_Reduce()` have the same type and size, so a reduce'd matrix is a matrix. If you reduce a row, the result will also be a row. If you expect to "reduce" a matrix into a row, then `MPI_Reduce()` is not a fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I expext MPI_Reduce() to go through my matrix columns and sum every row, just like it sums every array in the example above. Do I have to make a recvbuf also a raw type as a sendbuf for this or it's just not possible with MPI_Reduce()?

Comment: `MPI_Reduce()` takes a single `datatype` that is used for both `sendbuf` and `recvbuf`. I still do not understand what you want to achieve, and all I can say is `MPI_Reduce()` can sum the matrices from all your ranks into a resulting matrix with the same dimensions. If this is what you want to do, you can do it on one shot instead of iterating over the columns and/or rows.

Comment: Sorry for my english ) Just want every proc to have the respective raw sum of my matrix A. So if I have 4 proc and A[4][4] I want for instance 0 proc to have A[0][0] + A[0][1]+A[0][2]+A[0][3]

Comment: `MPI_Reduce()` reduces accross the MPI ranks. For example, you would get the sum of **all** `A[0]0]` in `result[0][0]`. If you want to sum `result[0][0:3]`, then it is up to you to do it (read MPI cannot help you here).

Comment: Oh, now I see, I got it! Thank you so much for your time!